# Ничего не происходит когда нажимаю на кнопку со слушателем

Tags: java, android

При нажатии на кнопку с данным слушателем ничего не происходит.

```
public void Nclick(View view){

    infoDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    infoDialog.setTitle("Логин");
    infoDialog.setCancelable(false);
    View vv = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_dialog, null);
    EditText et = (EditText) vv.findViewById(R.id.login);
    infoDialog.setView(vv);
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String pas = sPref.getString("password", "");
    et.setText(sPref.getString("login", ""));

    infoDialog.setPositiveButton("Войти", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            afterLogin(et.getText().toString(),"12345");
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    infoDialog.create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
infoDialog.show();
```